# How to extract zip files with multi parts using python script to run in Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

Good day,

I am very new on python language and I was assigned to build a python script that will get all the attachment files from emails. The attachment files had a multi-disk part (.zip,.z01,.z02,etc). A normal zip file without any multi-disk part can easily be extracted using zipfile module. This codes works:

```
password = get_data()
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(source_file_name) if isfile(join(source_file_name, f))]
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            file_name_split = file.split("_")
            resource_name = file_name_split[0]
            pswd = password[resource_name]
            if resource_name not in listdir('extracted/'):
                zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile('attachments/' +file)
                zip_ref.setpassword(pwd = bytes(pswd, 'utf-8'))
                zip_ref.extractall('extracted')
                zip_ref.close()
                os.unlink(source_file_name + file)
```

But I cannot use that code in a multi-disk file because the zip file module does not support ZIP files with appended comments, or multi-disk ZIP files as the documents said on Zip file module.
I search in google for alternatives and I come up using a 7z application by using the python subprocess module.
Here`s my code on this.

```
zip_exe = '"C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe"' + ' x ' '"' + tmp_folder + 'sample.zip' '"'
subprocess.Popen(zip_exe, shell = True, cwd = tmp_extracted_folder)
```

This works at my local using my desktop Windows 10 without any problems. But I was wondering, how can I put this script on Google cloud function? I`m not sure that this will work easily by just putting on this script. Do I need to install 7z application on cloud function? I`m not sure. Do you guys have any idea if this will work? I need help, I`m getting stuck on this application.

If there`s another way to workaround please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install a software on Cloud Functions because they do not allow you to interact at the server level, since it is a serverless platform that only executes single purpose functions triggered by events.

If you choose to go with the approach of using the 7zip application you would have to create a server instance for your application using compute engine, however, this would generate server costs for your project and I don't think it's the best solution for your problem.

What you could do is use different Python Libraries than ZipFile to unzip them programatically, which would run in a Cloud Function. Personally I would suggest you to use pyunpack, as it is the most complete unzipping library I found for Python. You can take a look at the documentation for it in this [link](https://pypi.org/project/pyunpack/) with instructions on how to implement it and examples, you could also try [libarchive](https://pypi.org/project/libarchive/) and [lmza](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/doc/USAGE.md) (depending on your python version).

**NOTE**: For pyunpack, you also need to import [patool](https://pypi.org/project/patool/), which is the "engine" it uses to unpack the files, otherwise it would only rely on ZipFile and it would not work.

Hope This helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did create a compute engine and its working now. I'm gonna try your suggestion for other libraries. Will if ever that may work. But bro thanks!